# Sending MIDI signal to Whammy Pedal

Tags: effects-pedal

Looking for a way of randomizing a continuous MIDI signal into the midi input on my Whammy Pedal to generate random pitch shifts.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Are you not sure how to generate random midi data?

Comment: Any further information? At the moment I think I would use an Arduino to do this (a bit of soldering and programming required, but several people have done similar things online.)  Alternatively there's probably ways to send the necessary MIDI messages from a sequencer (you would have to set up some semi-random pitch shifts.)

Comment: If you already have a midi "head" then it occurs to me that a piezo sensor + resistor setup that people use to add triggers to drums, couches, tin foil etc can be altered by replacing the piezo with an audio interface. Since audio on a wire is voltage, you can get a variable, random voltage by playing static/untuned AM radio etc. Make a tape loop and hit play.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way is to get a Molten MIDI box; it's a little box that sends patterns of CC's to your Whammy to make it do interesting pitch-shifty things.  You can even program your own patterns.  It's pretty neat.  Another way would be to draw a CC pattern in your DAW like Ableton and then send that out your MIDI interface to the Whammy.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Ableton you can use it's midi effects to create a real random effect (I'm not sure if it is a truly never repeating algorithm, but it will do).
Using the velocity effect, there is a random setting, if you set it to 100%, you will get midi data from 0 to 127, variating with each hit
I've also experimented with stringing different arps in parallel and series to make up certain patterns that take a long time before playing exactly the same.
But the cool thing is that you can write these midi notes to a new midi-track, which you can then re-use as new input for the same procedure.
And, so with some thinkering you might get a midi-stream for your Whammy that will blow your socks off ;-)